# change the color of the close button in fullscreen

Tags: flutter, dart

how to change button close (x) in flutter fullscreen dialog ?? Is that the default button for widgets that cannot be changed?
I want to change the default color (white) to black, because later the color of the appbar is white.

[image]

Comment: I also have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using iconTheme on the AppBar:

```
iconTheme: IconThemeData(
   color: Colors.black,
),
```